# To which audio format can I convert aac lost-free with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Since I did not manage to get the audio work with

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.avi
```

I'm searching for an audio format to which I can convert `aac` lost-free.
Does such an audio-format exist for this scope?

Comment: AAC is lossy. Period.

Comment: Are you talking about **ALAC** (Apple Lossless Audio Codec)? As in you want to convert a file in alac to something else?

Comment: You can convert it to a lossless format such as FLAC, but you'd get the worst of both worlds: quality of a lossy file and size of a lossless file...

Comment: well, there is always uncompressed PCM...